# Calculate central area in image array

Tags: java, android, bitmap, pseudocode

I have and array of 80 integers

```
int[800] px;
```

From this array I create an image of 80x100 points (h: 80, w:100)

For finding centered pixel in array I use:

```
px[(w >> 1) * (h + 1)]
```

But now I need to find 4x4 (16centered pixels and average them. Can you please help me do this?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by averaging the cells?

Comment: Avarage value that is in the area. For example: (px[460]+px[461]+....+px[563])/16=?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a one-dimention array (`p`), whitch contains an image (`im[x][y] = p[im.width*x+y]`) an you want to know which is the middle 4x4 of that image and compute the average of those 16 pixels.
The middle of the 80x100 pixels image is at (40,50); (I would use a 3x3 window instead of 4x4) so you need the pixels (40+i,50+i), where i in {-1,0,1}. Now you can use a variable to compute the average of 3x3=9 pixels value

There is a library, OpenCV that can do alot of stuffs and can be integrated with Java.